# reminder wp_schedule_event

Tags: plugins, wp-cron

Hi I use this plugin for create events `https://wordpress.org/plugins/modern-events-calendar-lite/` and this for send notification on my android app. `https://github.com/dream-space/wp-fcm`

I make modification on plugin to send reminder notification for upcoming events (3days) before.
The modification look like like.

`

```
 function fcm_main_get_option_event(){
  $options = get_option('fcm_event_setting');
  if(!is_array($options)){
    $options = array(
        'event_check' => 0,
    );
 }

return $options;
}

if (!wp_next_scheduled('my_task_hook')) {
wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'my_task_hook' );
}
add_action ( 'my_task_hook', 'my_task_function' );
```

`

And function to send notification:

`

```
function my_task_function() {
$options  = get_option('fcm_event_setting');
 //  $is_send_notif = false;
if(!empty($options['event_check'])) {
   $is_send_notif = true;
  $args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'mec-events',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
  );

$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 

    
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
$datetime2 = date("Y-m-d"); 
$my_meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'mec_start_date', true ); 
$diff = strtotime($my_meta) - strtotime($datetime2);
    $gap = abs(round($diff / 86400)); 

    
    if($gap == '3'){
         $is_send_notif = true;
         $title = 'Потсетување';
         $event = "POTSETNIK 1";
        $body    = 'For '.$gap.' days :' .get_the_title();

    }


    if($is_send_notif == true){
    $message = array(
        'title'     => $title,
        'content'   =>  'For '.$gap.' days:' .get_the_title()

    );

    $total = fcm_data_get_all_count();
    if($total <= 0) return;

    $respon  = fcm_notif_divide_send("", $total, $message);

    fcm_data_insert_log($title, $content, "ALL", $event, $respon['status']);
}
    endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
}
}
```

`

This work, but send notification 3 days before, and 3 days after the event.

Where is the problem.

Thanks?

Answer (score 0):

It's because your code is *explicitly written* to ignore whether or not the event is in the past or the future.

See here:

```
$diff = strtotime($my_meta) - strtotime($datetime2);
```

If the event date is in the future, `$diff` will be a positive number, but if it's in the past, it will be a negative number. Then the very next line is:

```
$gap = abs(round($diff / 86400));
```

The whole point of the `abs()` function is to make sure a number is a positive number. Which means that the result will be exactly the same whether the event is in the past or in the future.

If you only want to send a notification for upcoming events then you need to know if the number is negative. So just remove `abs()` and make sure that you're only checking for `3` and not `-3`:

```
$diff = strtotime($my_meta) - strtotime($datetime2);
$gap = round($diff / 86400); 


if($gap === 3){
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks,Let me test.

Comment: with this changes not send notification. :/